# Switzerland Schengen visa: no answer from consulate after declaration of sponsorship

Tags: schengen, switzerland

I applied for a Schengen visa on September 6th, after a week (Sep 13th),the Swiss embassy told me the visa was pre-approved and gave me back my passport with a sponsorship letter application which I had to send to my sponsor in Switzerland. They told me they would call me again as soon as the document is processed there to bring my the passport and issue the visa.

We were very worried cause online it says the process can take up to 6 weeks or more and I don't really have that time since my flight will be on October the 10th, so after another week we called the authorities which process the sponsorship letter and explained the situation to them.
They were very polite and helped us to get the document processed the same day, and they said the Swiss embassy in my country already had the confirmation of the sponsorship letter.

The thing is, the embassy in my country got the sponsorship letter confirmation last Thursday and I haven't received any call yet after 3 working days, I don't understand why they're taking so long.
Was the visa denied? If so, would they give me a letter with the reasons why?
My flight scheduled to leave in 2 weeks and I still haven't heard anything from them.

Comment: Call them and ask, only way to go about it really